# Why can't I webscrape the table that I want?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, beautifulsoup, wikipedia

I am new to BeautifulSoup and I wanted to try out some web scraping. For my little project, I wanted to get the Golden State Warrior win rate from Wikipedia. I was planning to get the table that had that information and make it into a panda so I could graph it over the years. However, my code selects the Table Key table instead of the Seasons table. I know this is because they are the same type of table (wikitable), but I don't know how to solve this problem. I am sure that there is an easy explanation that I am missing. Can someone please explain how to fix my code and explain how I could choose which tables to web scrape in the future? Thanks!

```
c_data = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Golden_State_Warriors_seasons" #wikipedia page
c_page = urllib.request.urlopen(c_data)
c_soup = BeautifulSoup(c_page, "lxml")
c_table=c_soup.find('table', class_='wikitable') #this is the problem
c_year = []
c_rate = []
for row in c_table.findAll('tr'): #setup for dataframe
  cells=row.findAll('td')
  if len(cells)==13:
    c_year = c_year.append(cells[0].find(text=True))
    c_rate = c_rate.append(cells[9].find(text=True))
print(c_year, c_rate)
```

Comment: I also imported beautifulsoup and urllib.request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Use [`pd.read_html`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html) to get all the tables

- This function returns a list of dataframes

  - `tables[0]` through `tables[17]`, in this case

```py
import pandas as pd

# read tables
tables = pd.read_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Golden_State_Warriors_seasons')

print(len(tables))
>>> 18

tables[0]
          0                                             1
0       AHC                  NBA All-Star Game Head Coach
1      AMVP            All-Star Game Most Valuable Player
2       COY                             Coach of the Year
3      DPOY                  Defensive Player of the Year
4    Finish          Final position in division standings
5        GB  Games behind first-place team in division[b]
6   Italics                            Season in progress
7    Losses               Number of regular season losses
8       EOY                         Executive of the Year
9      FMVP                   Finals Most Valuable Player
10      MVP                          Most Valuable Player
11      ROY                            Rookie of the Year
12      SIX                         Sixth Man of the Year
13     SPOR                           Sportsmanship Award
14     Wins                 Number of regular season wins

# display all dataframes in tables
for i, table in enumerate(tables):
    print(f'Table {i}')
    display(table)
    print('\n')
```

### Select specific table

```py
df_i_want = tables[x]  # x is the specified table, 0 indexed

# delete tables
del(tables)
```